# Remove spaces and tabs within a string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

How can I remove specific whitespace within a string in python.

My input string is:,

```
str1 = """vendor_id\t: GenuineIntel
        cpu family\t: 6
        model\t\t: 58
        model name\t: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz
        stepping\t: 9
        cpu MHz\t\t: 2485.659
        cache size\t: 6144 KB
        fpu\t\t: yes
        fpu_exception\t: yes
        cpuid level\t: 5
        wp\t\t: yes"""
```

My required output is:

```
>>>print str1
vendor_id: GenuineIntel
cpu family: 6
model: 58
model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping: 9
cpu MHz: 2485.659
cache size: 6144 KB
fpu: yes
fpu_exception: yes
cpuid level: 5
wp: yes
```

Comment: Are you sure your output string doesn't have any space in it.

Comment: I've edited your sample to a) be valid Python, and b) replace the existing tabs in it with `\t` characters, since that's what is important here but wasn't visible. Please do use `print repr(str1)` to show us what is *really* in there if you can.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you want to remove the whitespace from the start of lines, and remove all whitespace before a colon. Use regular expressions:

```
import re

re.sub(r'(^[ \t]+|[ \t]+(?=:))', '', str1, flags=re.M)
```

This picks out spaces and tabs at the start of lines (`^[ \t]*`, `^` is the start of a line, `[ \t]` is a space or tab, `+` is 1 or more), *or* it picks out spaces and tabs right before a colon (`[ \t]+` is 1 or more spaces and tabs, `(?=:)` means that a `:` character must follow but isn't included in what is picked) and then replaces those spaces and tabs with an empty string. The `flags=re.M` is there to make sure the pattern works on each individual line.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = """vendor_id\t: GenuineIntel
...         cpu family\t: 6
...         model\t\t: 58
...         model name\t: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz
...         stepping\t: 9
...         cpu MHz\t\t: 2485.659
...         cache size\t: 6144 KB
...         fpu\t\t: yes
...         fpu_exception\t: yes
...         cpuid level\t: 5
...         wp\t\t: yes"""
>>> print re.sub(r'(^[ \t]+|[ \t]+(?=:))', '', str1, flags=re.M)
vendor_id: GenuineIntel
cpu family: 6
model: 58
model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping: 9
cpu MHz: 2485.659
cache size: 6144 KB
fpu: yes
fpu_exception: yes
cpuid level: 5
wp: yes
```

If your input string does **not** have leading whitespace (and you just indented your sample yourself to make it look lined up), then all you want to remove is tabs:

```
str1 = str1.replace('\t', '')
```

and be done with it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you mean by "randomly", but you can remove all tabs with:

```
str1 = str1.replace("\t", "")
```

Comment: That won't be enough here if the leading whitespace or whitespace before the `:` characters contains regular spaces too.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your answer:

```
str1 = """vendor_id\t: GenuineIntel
    cpu family\t: 6
    model\t\t: 58
    model name\t: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz
    stepping\t: 9
    cpu MHz\t\t: 2485.659
    cache size\t: 6144 KB
    fpu\t\t: yes
    fpu_exception\t: yes
    cpuid level\t: 5
    wp\t\t: yes"""
arr = [line.strip() for line in str1.split('\n')]
for line in arr:
    print line.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def invitation_ics():
    text = f"""BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:CONFIRMED
    """ # text
return text
```

out not tab
Output:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:CONFIRMED

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = str1.replace("\t", "").replace(" ", "")
```

it would replace the tabs first and then white spaces.

Comment: This replaces **all** whitespace with nothing. The spaces after the colon and in between the words should be preserved.